# How to get dictionary keys using a tuple, where dictionary keys are stored in list and values in tuple

Tags: python

```
dictionary = {}

my_list = ['a','b','c','d']

for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
    dictionary[my_list[i]] = (my_list[i],)


for i in sorted (dictionary.keys()):
    k = dictionary[i]
    """code here"""
```

For the above code I need to get the output as :  
a  
b  
c

I know if we put print(i), we will get the desired output, but the answer expected is in terms of K.
Actual answer is: print(k[0]),which I am unable to understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you define values of `dictionary` equal to a tuple here:

```
dictionary[my_list[i]] = (my_list[i],)
```

k is a tuple which means for it to print the actual value you need to get the first item in k by using the following:

```
dictionary = {}

my_list = ['a','b','c','d']

for i in range(len(my_list)-1):
    dictionary[my_list[i]] = (my_list[i],)


for i in sorted (dictionary.keys()):
    k = dictionary[i]
    print(k[0])
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
```

`k[0]` just gets the first item in the tuple `('a',)`. This makes it print `a` instead of `('a',)`.

Comment: Great, Thanks for the explanation